# Disable the animation for Close button in SearchViewController

Tags: ios, animation, uisearchbar

I have a ViewController that has a TableView and a SearchBar and Search Display Controller inside.
When I press the Close button to finish the search, the animation goes weird and ugly.
How can I disable that animation?

Help please, thanks.

Comment: is this animation something you control, or built-in animation to dismiss (or pop) a view controller, or?

Comment: is a built-in animation @MichaelDautermann to close the Search Display Controller.
This is why I want to disable this animation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288486/autoresizing-mask-from-searchbar